# How to type in such a diagram that is shown in the picture of an isotherm?

Tags: diagrams, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

[image: PV-diagram of an isotherm with some segments of adiabats]

How can I recreate such a diagram? with the line segments and not necessarily with the points (V_2, P_5, T_5), ..., etc.

Comment: Is this post helpful? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706978/267375

Comment: Yes! I think this is good however, missing the line segments I need the most.

Comment: You're unlikely to find an answer that has everything you're looking for. There are plenty of online resources that you can use to learn the basics of TikZ and PGFPlots (e.g., the packages' documentation). I highly recommend that you do learn the basics so that you can add the line segments yourself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! My 2-cents would be to study the pgfplots package; specifically, the axis environment and the \addplot command. Check out Dr. Trefor Bazett on YouTube too. I recommend this retrospectively, as I wish I has received advice like this when I was just beginning with TikZ. :) (Just studying the TikZ manual without guidance can be **quite** dry)

Comment: @bonk I really would like to, but at the moment the only time I have is being put into studying the courses I'm taking more. However, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Pseudonym123 Yess! I actually started using latex after I watched his first and second tutorials; amazing. I think I have watched his TikZ video.. i might want to rewatch it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As some comments stated, we'd like to see your own attempts here, first. However, because this diagram involves some interesting aspects, I'll sketch a path towards your final diagram. BTW, this is more or less the procedure to come up with drawings.

#### Where to find more

I suggest to skim through or read the tutorial sections in the Tikz manual, either as [html](https://tikz.dev/) of [pdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Also look up all relevant Tikz-commands I'm using.

#### Basic idea

Let's have a look at the basic idea first:

- draw the axes
- draw the lower curve
- indicate points needed for your dottings
- connect points above the lower curve

Axes: nothing strange her ... just draw them.

```
    % ~~~ axes ~~~
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
```

Now, the lower curve seems to be complicated, while it's not when you understood the path-concept of Tikz. Basically you draw a line between two points `\draw (1,3) -- (4,1);` . To make it curved, as one way to do it just replace `--` by `to[out=,in=]` and specify the outgoing and incoming angles. The path starts with `\draw` and ends with `;` . So let's do a bit more actions on this path before it ends. Put a `node` after the last coordinate drawn to put the T1 label. Insert two more `node`s between start and end point, where we only will use their coordinates (A) and (B) and fine tune their position on this path by using `[pos=]`. Kindly watch the dropped `\` inside the path.

```
    % ~~~ lower curve: a path with many actions ~~~~~   
    \draw (1,3) to[out=-60,in=170]  % start point, towards ...
    node[pos=.8] (A) {A}            % basically, store coordinates
    node[pos=.6] (B) {B}            % (A) and (B)
    (4,1) node[anchor=west]{$T_1$}  % end point + some node as label    
    ;                               % end of this path
```

We need an other point (C) above (B), so let's put another `\node`, using a `[yshift=]`

```
    % ~~~ put a node//coordinate above (B) ~~~
    \node (C) at ([yshift=6mm]B) {C};
```

Finally, let's connect (A), (C) and (B), again with some curved line:

```
    % ~~~ connect A, C and B ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) to[out=140,in=-70] (C) -- (B);
```

[image: basicIdea]

#### Refinements

These are the changes and add-ons:

- define some styles: `crd` to render the dummy nodes with circles, `ln` for the line
- remember `coordinate (X)`  along the x-axis for later
- remove text from nodes A, B and C AND use the `crd` style
- draw with arrow and label for the `(label)`
- calculate coordinate (V4) under (B) reusing (X), put a `\node`, `\draw` a tick

For the  `shifted arrow` in your line there are several ways to do it. I used the lazy variant, and here are further options:

- omitting the arrow
- using the decorations library
- put an intermediate point between A and B (and adjust the angles, if needed)
- etc.

[image: refinements]

#### Complete code

This code will create two pages (one for each tikzpicture environment) of drawings with adjusted page geometry.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 % ~~~ (I) basic ideas ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ axes ~~~
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
    
    % ~~~ lower curve: a path with many actions ~~~~~   
    \draw (1,3) to[out=-60,in=170]  % start point, towards ...
    node[pos=.8] (A) {A}            % basically, store coordinates
    node[pos=.6] (B) {B}            % (A) and (B)
    (4,1) node[anchor=west]{$T_1$}  % end point + some node as label    
    ;                               % end of this path
    
    % ~~~ put a node//coordinate above (B) ~~~
    \node (C) at ([yshift=6mm]B) {C};
    
    % ~~~ connect A, C and B ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) to[out=140,in=-70] (C) -- (B);
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 
 
 % ~~~ (II) fine print ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[   % some self-defined styles
    crd/.style={minimum size=1mm,       % puts the dots
                inner sep=0pt,circle,draw,fill},
    ln/.style={blue, line width=1.5pt},
 ]
    % ~~~ axes ~~~
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) coordinate (X);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
    
    % ~~~ lower curve: a path with many actions ~~~~~   
    \draw (1,3) to[out=-60,in=170]  % start point, towards ...
    node[pos=.8,crd] (A) {}         % basically, store coordinates
    node[pos=.6,crd] (B) {}         % (A) and (B)
    (4,1) node[anchor=west]{$T_1$}  % end point + some node as label    
    ;                               % end of this path
    
    % ~~~ put a node//coordinate above (B) ~~~
    \node[crd] (C) at ([yshift=6mm]B) {};
    
    % ~~~ connect A, C and B ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[ln,->] (A) to[out=140,in=-70] (C);
    \draw[ln]    (C) -- (B);
    
    % ~~~ put some label ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<-] (C) -- +(45:15mm) node[anchor=west] {$(V_4, P_4, T_4)$};
    
    % ~~~ perpendicular below points ~~~~~~~
    \coordinate           (V4) at (B |- X); % projection onto x-axis
    \node[yshift=-3mm] at (V4) {$V_4$};     % the label
    \draw (V4) -- +(0,.2);                  % the tick
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice and clean explanation :-D

Comment: Thank you, @MadyYuvi

Comment: Oh wow! that's quite good, thank you very much.